# What should be cronExpression for below cronschedule using quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I am trying [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) and could able to create proper expression for below scenarios

1.Job run every 60 min between 7:30 am to 8 pm

2.Job run every 40-80 min (shoud be random) between 8 am to 8 pm

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are better off using the DailyTimeIntervalTrigger that is intended to be used for this type of schedules. See the attached screenshot for an example of a DailyTimeIntervalTrigger attributes for your use-case.

[image: Example of DailyTimeIntervalTrigger to execute job every 60 minutes between 7:30am and 8pm.].

2. In Quartz it is not possible to create static triggers that execute a job at random intervals. However you can dynamically reschedule your jobs in its execute method. Basically you will need to create a CronTrigger that executes your job at 8am and in your job implementation class you will create a new trigger (probably a SimpleTrigger) that executes your job at:

> current_execution_start_time + random_value_between(40,80) minutes

You will need to check if the computed next start time does not exceed 8pm. If so, you will skip the trigger creation.

Alternatively you could make of some Quartz job chaining framework that allows you to chain your job to itself while allowing you to dynamically compute the target job's start time. For example, our product [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com) can handle this easily.